# How to specify in swagger API param in path can be 1 or more separated by comma

Tags: javascript, api, swagger

I am trying to tell swagger that I want id in path but it can be one id or multiple separated by comma.
tried array type didn't work for 1 number

any suggestions?

```
/dams/{dam_id}:
  x-swagger-router-controller: Dams
  get:
    operationId: dam
    parameters:
      - name: dam_id
        in: path
        description: dam id
        required: true
        type: array
        items:
          type: integer
        collectionFormat: csv
```

I expect to be able to call one or multiple id

Comment: Your definition is correct. What do you mean by "did not work for 1 number"?

Comment: What server-side framework do you use? (e.g. [swagger-tools](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools) or [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) or something else)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it's better to filter a list of resources, for example :

- `/dam?dam_id=12345,24593,87322`

Your swagger definition should looks like this :

```
/dams:
  x-swagger-router-controller: Dams
  get:
    operationId: dam
    parameters:
      - name: dam_id
        in: query
        description: dam id
        required: true
        type: array
        items:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        collectionFormat: csv
```

However, you

Comment: Arrays as path parameters are perfectly valid according to the OpenAPI Specification. This is likely a limitation or misconfiguration of OP's server-side framework.

Comment: Thanks @Helen, always sharing great information about Swagger.